# Is user data part of an AGPL-derived-application?

Tags: gpl, agpl-3.0

Assuming we have a kubernetes application stack consisting of - among other things - MongoDB and Metabase. Metabase is APGLv3 licensed. We share the combined code as e.g. helm charts publicly on github. Now we host this application internally and save user data to the database and use Metabase to create dashboards.

Am I correct to assume that any user data does not fall under the copyleft license? And that the approach described above fulfills the copyleft license well?

//EDIT: I've seen [Can I use AGPL component to create a data file for commercial application?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/can-i-use-agpl-component-to-create-a-data-file-for-commercial-application), but this referred to software output.

Comment: Q1. Did you modify any of the AGPL code that you are hosting? Q2. Did you place a notice somewhere in your app and/or documentation to advise users of where they can find the code (e.g. a Github link).

Comment: Also, I'm not an expert on Kubernetes, but it sounds to me like Helm Charts are only one part of the application, or that it's a sort of configuration element to the app. Maybe you could clarify whether you're sharing the whole code of your app or not. Anyway, this is relevant if you modified the code, due to AGPL requirements.

Comment: I answered your question, but Brandin is correct: if all you're doing is creating helm charts, you're not modifying any of the software and thus its license terms do not burden you.  Merely bundling doesn't create a derived work, and most licenses make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

The AGPL has no requirements for sharing of user data.  This was the reason for the [creation of the CAL](https://opensource.org/license/cal-1-0/), which does have limited requirements for sharing data as well as code.  If the AGPL had covered any data, the authors of the CAL would have used it.

Note, though, that MongoDB is under the [SSPL](https://www.mongodb.com/licensing/server-side-public-license), a non-OSS license, and not the AGPL, so the SSPL's terms may affect you.